# object required error on function call

Tags: vba, outlook

I made a Class Module and named it Time.  I wanted to have a function in it that created an instance of the Time object and returned it.  See code below.  If you can think of a better way to write the function, I'm all ears.  The problem I'm having, as it stands is when I make the following statement:

> tsheet.MondayStart = Time.Construct(Item.Value)

A debug.print statement prior to this call shows that Item.Value is "08:30".
tsheet is of type TimeSheet and MondayStart property is expecting to be assigned an object of type Time.  However, when this statement executes at runtime, I get the object required error.  I even tried removing the paranthesis, but all that does is bring up another error "Compile Error: Expected end of statement"

How do I fix this?  Please advise.  Too bad vba doesn't support the notion of construtors :-(

Alan

```
'IN TIME CLASS MODULE
Public Function Construct(Value As String) As Time
  'This function expects a string formatted like: 08:30
  'Time.Delimiter returns ":"
  Dim tempTime As Time
  Dim vhours As Integer
  Dim vminutes As Integer
  Dim arrTime() As Time

  arrTime = Split(Value, Time.Delimiter)
  hours = CInt(Trim(arrTime(0)))
  minutes = CInt(Trim(arrTime(1)))
  Set tempTime = New Time
  tempTime.hours = vhours
  tempTime.minutes = vminutes

  Construct = tempTime
End Function
```

Comment: I think a SET is missing in tsheet.MondayStart = Time.Construct(Item.Value)?

Comment: I tried adding SET but at runtime I'm still getting "object required".  As I step through the line: Set tsheet.MondayStart = Time.Construct(Item.Value), Item.Value returns the parameter "08:30", immediately after that it kicks out to error.  I'm thinking it has something against my Construct() function, though I don't know what that could be?  Please advise.

Comment: Time is a keyword in VBA, can you try changing Time into some other variable name?

Comment: It looks like you are instantiating an instance of your Time class inside your Time class. I've never tried to do that, but it seems like a bad idea.

Comment: have added another fix, have a look

Answer (score 1):

Actually I suggest you use the already implemented VBA methods DateValue and TimeValue which will accept a string and give you what you need.

I am not sure you need to re-invent the wheel here.  Of course I might have missed something so please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use the result of the new as follows:

```
Set MonStart = New TimeFrame
Set tsheet.MondayStart = MonStart.Initialize(MonStart, Item.Value)
```

(For comparision, here's previous:

```
Set MonStart = New TimeFrame
Set tsheet.MondayStart = TimeFrame.Initialize(MonStart, Item.Value)
```

)

Also use `Set` on function return value assignment.

for the first code example:

```
...
    Set Construct = tempTime
End Function
```

and for the other code example:

```
...
    Set Initialize = Value
End Function
```

Comment: OK...I tried that.  I still get the error.  This is a tough one! The function seems staight forward enough.  We're obviously missing something else?  Would it help if you had the whole class module to look at?

Comment: if that gets further, then it was the use of the module itself as an object that VBA didn't like (though it should have complained at compile time, not runtime if you ask my opinion).  And if this works, you won't need to pass `MonStart` as a parameter, too (you can return `Me` instead).